# When loading the facebook widget on a local page, it sets the created iFrame's width/height styles to 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm loading the widget in a local HTML file and it *does* load, but the Facebook code sets the iframe (and containing `span` to be 0px in width and height. Why does this occur?

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-width="300px" data-height="500px" data-tabs="events" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i take it facebook doesn't allow to change the widget size?

Comment: @Keith No, I can do it in javascript and then it shows. But it initially shows as 0px *only* if loaded from a local file

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “local file” – are you viewing this in your browser via the file system? If so, you should install a local web server, so that you can access it via `http://`  instead.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, from the file system. I made that change but am now getting this new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186827/when-loading-the-facebook-widget-on-a-local-page-it-sets-the-created-iframes-w

Comment: That's a link to this question...

Comment: @Igy Sorry, posted it in the wrong thread